# How to use Kotlin Android Extensions in Java

Tags: java, android, kotlin

How can I use Kotlin Android Extensions to skip `findViewById` in an Activity while coding with Java for Android development?

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

Comment: besides butterknife, you can also use databinding  https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html. (more info here https://medium.com/google-developers/no-more-findviewbyid-457457644885).

Answer (score 3):

Kotlin Android Extensions is a plugin for the Kotlin compiler which transforms your Kotlin code at compile time. Since the Kotlin compiler does not compile your Java sources, there is no way for the plugin to work with Java files. There, you'll have to stick to manual lookups or using something like [ButterKnife](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife).

Answer (score 2):

Here is [Butterknife](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife) library that is very popular among Android Developers including me.

See a sample.

```
class ExampleActivity extends Activity {
  @BindView(R.id.user) EditText username;
  @BindView(R.id.pass) EditText password;

  @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.simple_activity);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    // TODO Use fields...
  }
}
```

Doesn't this looks pretty clean and short?

For adding in your project just add this light weight dependency.

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
  annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
}
```

Happy coding :)